# UnicodeDecodeError on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, sentiment-analysis

Having some problems. I'm doing a TwitterSentimentAnalysis on a  dataset of length 1.6 million. Since my pc could not do the work (due to so many computations), the professor told me to use the university server.

I just realiazed that on the server, python version is 2.7 that it does not allow me to use the parameter *encoding* in csv reader for reading the file.

Anytime I got the `UnicodeDecodeError`, I have to manually remove the tweet from the dataset otherwise I can't do the rest. I have tried to go on all the question on the site but I resolved nothing.

I just want to skip the line who raises the error, since the set is big enough to allow me a good analysis.

```
class UTF8Recoder:
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')

class UnicodeReader:
    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
    def next(self):
        '''next() -> unicode
        This function reads and returns the next line as a Unicode string.
        '''
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8", errors='replace') for s in row]
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

def extraction(file, textCol, sentimentCol):
    "The function reads the tweets"
    #fp = open(file, "r",encoding="utf8")
    fp = open(file, "r")
    tweetreader = UnicodeReader(fp)
    #tweetreader = csv.reader( fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\' )
    tweets = []
    for row in tweetreader:
        # It takes the column in which the tweets and the sentiment are
        if row[sentimentCol]=='positive' or row[sentimentCol]=='4':
            tweets.append([remove_stopwords(row[textCol]), 'positive']);
        else:
            if row[sentimentCol]=='negative' or row[sentimentCol]=='0':
                tweets.append([remove_stopwords(row[textCol]), 'negative']);
            else:
               if row[sentimentCol]=='irrilevant' or row[sentimentCol]=='2' or row[sentimentCol]=='neutral':
                   tweets.append([remove_stopwords(row[textCol]), 'neutral']);

    tweets = filterWords(tweets)
    fp.close()
    return tweets;
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentimentAnalysis_v4.py", line 165, in <module>
    newTweets = extraction("sentiment2.csv",5,0)
  File "sentimentAnalysis_v4.py", line 47, in extraction
    for row in tweetreader:
  File "sentimentAnalysis_v4.py", line 29, in next
    row = self.reader.next()
  File "sentimentAnalysis_v4.py", line 19, in next
    return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 615, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 530, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 477, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 48: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain the data is encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: Hrm, the traceback you are showing suggests that `codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)` returned an object that doesn't return `unicode` when you call `next` on it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters if it wasn't, should it read the other tweets anyway?
The tweets I have to manually remove are of the type "à€€€€" and strange stuff like this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters unluckly, I am not the only one using the server, so I can't ask them to update Python for me. Using another dataset I got no problem for it.
So, is it a wayto bypass those kinda lines and go to the next one? I have to deliver the project in one week and I am into s**t.

Comment: I gave you a work-around; the exact 2.7 Python version here doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have input data that is malformed, I'd not use `codecs` here to do the reading.

Use the newer [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) and specify a error handling strategy; `'replace'` should do:

```
class ForgivingUTF8Recoder:
    def __init__(self, filename, encoding):
        self.reader = io.open(f, newline='', encoding=encoding, errors='replace')
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
```

I set the `newline` handling to `''` to make sure the CSV module gets to handle newlines in values correctly.

Instead of passing in an open file, just pass in the filename:

```
tweetreader = UnicodeReader(file)
```

This won't let you *skip* faulty lines, it instead will handle faulty lines by replacing characters that cannot be decoded with the [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://codepoints.net/U+FFFD); you can still look for those in your columns if you want to skip the whole row.