# Upload rows to existing BigQuery table using Python Client Library utf8 can't decode

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a csv file to an existing table on BigQuery. According to Bigquery's [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery-usage.html), this is how you do it:

```
ROWS_TO_INSERT = [
    (u'Phred Phlyntstone', 32),
    (u'Wylma Phlyntstone', 29),
]

table.insert_data(ROWS_TO_INSERT)
```

And here's is my code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# enter credentials
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('my_dataset')
table = dataset.table('my_table')

# open csv file and get a list of rows in the form of tuples
with open('my_data.csv') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
ROWS_TO_INSERT = [tuple(x.split(",")) for x in content
table.reload()

# everything above worked well, but the below line got a utf8 can't decode error
table.insert_data(ROWS_TO_INSERT)
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/Users/layla.zhang/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py", line 770, in insert_data
    data=data)
  File "/Users/layla.zhang/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 294, in api_request
    data = json.dumps(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 68: invalid continuation byte
```

I spent a lot of time researching similar issues and tried a number of encoding/decoding workaround, but nothing worked so far. What do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError on Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494869/unicodedecodeerror-on-python-2-7)

Comment: I actually came across this post and tried UnicodeReader(file) and got the same error, also tried io.path(file, errors='replace'), weirdly got 101 rows instead of 26 rows (which is correct).